# Passing Command Line Arguments From a File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python script to run my vb.net project executable. The problem I ran into is when I read the lines and then use a for loop to use the individual line (IP) as an argument to my application, this does not work. However when I use any other String it does work. So it does not read the IP from ipaddress.txt but it does take an IP if entered manual as the argument instead of 'line'.

```
import subprocess
f = open('ipaddress.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
   subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\YYYYY\\OneDrive - XXXX
   \\Visual-Studio-Projects\\Map_Tester\\bin\\Map200_Tester.exe', 'line'])
```

Any details why this is happening are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have `'line'` enclosed in quotes signifying it as a string. But you want `line` to be read as a variable, so simply remove the quotes in `line` in your for loop, which will do what you want: iterate over each `for line in lines:`

```
import subprocess
f = open('ipaddress.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for line in lines:
    subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Users\\YYYYY\\OneDrive - XXXX
    \\Visual-Studio-Projects\\Map_Tester\\bin\\Map200_Tester.exe'], line[:-1])
```

This edit would remove any newline character from your `line` variable.

Comment: see my edit, your lines could contain newline `\n` characters, this would strip those without messing up the format of your code. If this doesn't work, try `str(line)` or `str(line[:-1])`

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that I read lines from the text and then use a single line as my argument whereas I should use a single word.

Comment: do the lines of your file contain more than the ipaddress string?

Comment: see my most recent edit, you may have had the bracket in the wrong place. I think it is supposed to encase the file. Again, try `line`, `str(line)`, `line[:-1]`, and `str(line[:-1])` if any individual case does not work. I think your ipaddresses probably have new line chars so you might need to strip them using the `line[:-1]`

Comment: it still doesn't work with any of those variations :(